# How to force Yarn classic to resolve different "deep" dependency

Tags: yarnpkg

I currently have

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "svg-chameleon": "^0.5.2",
    }
```

where `0.5.2` is [the latest version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-chameleon/v/0.5.2), `svg-chameleon` has `"svg-sprite": "^1.5.0"` [as dependency](https://github.com/christian-reichart/svg-chameleon/blob/6efa0b75018174bc24c9411a91c5a92521c03c83/package.json#L33), wchin in turn has `"@xmldom/xmldom": "^0.7.5"` which [has a vulnerability I try to address](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-crh6-fp67-6883)

Since all the dependencies are "soft", e.g. "^" it should be possible to bump `@xmldom/xmldom` to at least 0.7.7. which is supposedly fixed.

Since I can't bump `svg-chameleon` which is at the top of it's version I thought I should use [resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/):

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "svg-chameleon": "^0.5.2",
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "@xmldom/xmldom": "0.7.7"
    },
```

but after running `yarn install` (I even tried `yarn upgrade @xmldom/xmldom`) the version is still the same

```
$ yarn why @xmldom/xmldom
yarn why v1.22.19
=> Found "@xmldom/xmldom@0.7.5"
```

So how do I force it? It all seems to be possible: it's a patch version change, all packages should be compatible and they seem ok according to their definitions in `package.json`. Yet yarn refuses to do what it's asked for. Am I missing something? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not mentioned explicitly, but the key values in the `resolutions` are relative to your project.

To make it work what I needed to do was:

```
    "resolutions": {
        "**/svg-chameleon/svg-sprite/@xmldom/xmldom": "^0.7.7"
    },
```

Apparently you could also do

```
    "resolutions": {
        "**/@xmldom/xmldom": "^0.7.7"
    },
```

But this might affect other dependencies resolutions that have `@xmldom/xmldom` down beneath. So be careful, if there was another dependency that required `@xmldom: "5.1"` - it might get resolved wrong.

Also a tip I learned as well: One does not need to run `yarn install` to test resolutions. `yarn why` is enough, and once the resolution is picked up - run `yarn install` and commit changes.